# Make a scatter colorbar display only a subset of the vmin/vmax

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I have a situation where I want to create a colorbar whose colors (associated with a scatter plot) span a particular range, but only *display* a subset of that range on the colorbar itself.  I can do it with `contourf`, because I can set `vmin` and `vmax` independently of the contour levels, but I can't figure out how to do it with scatter. See the following:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 101)
x_arr = np.sin(x)
y_arr = np.cos(x)
arr = y_arr[:,None] * x_arr[None,:]

arr = np.where(arr < 0, arr*4, arr)
ptslist = np.array([-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1], dtype=np.float32)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(11,5), nrows=1, ncols=2)

# I can achieve my desired behavior with contourf
cont = axs[0].contourf(x, x, arr, levels=np.linspace(-4,1,11),
                       cmap='BrBG_r', vmin=-4, vmax=4)
div0 = make_axes_locatable(axs[0])
cax0 = div0.append_axes('right', '5%', '2%')
plt.colorbar(cont, cax=cax0)

# I can't make this colorbar do a similar thing
sc = axs[1].scatter(np.arange(-4, 2), np.arange(-4, 2), c=ptslist, cmap='BrBG_r',
                    marker='o', s=144, edgecolors='black', vmin=-4, vmax=4)
div1 = make_axes_locatable(axs[1])
cax1 = div1.append_axes('right', '5%', '2%')
cb = plt.colorbar(sc, cax=cax1)
```

This yields this figure:
[image: colorbar -4 to 4]

I want the diverging colormap to be centered with white at zero, and the color values displayed linearly on both sides of zero.  Both *plots* do this fine.  However, I don't want the extra values from 1 to 4 to display on the right colorbar (see how the left colorbar stops at 1).

My first thought was `ylim`, but this line:

```
cb.ax.set_ylim(-4, 1)
```

causes this strange thing to happen:

[image: colorbar is squished]

If I use `set_ticks`, it just removes absent ticks, and doesn't change the limits.  Is there any way to make this happen nicely?

I'm using matplotlib 1.5.0.

p.s. I've also tried a mid-point-centered subclass of Normalize that I found on SO, but it scales the positive and negative values independently, which I don't want (it makes the values of +1.0 dark brown, and I want it to still be light brown, unless I set `vmax=4`, at which point I have exactly the same problem).

Comment: Do you care about whether the two colorbars are actually the same, or do you just want them to represent the same regions of colorspace?  Your contour data includes more distinct values than your scatter data, so it stands to reason its colorbar would be more "detailed" (i.e., include more "shades" along the spectrum of the colormap).

Comment: No, the contour colorbar is just there for illustration - I don't care about the "detail", I just care about the limits.  i.e. I want the top of the right colorbar to be light brown at 1.0 rather than the dark brown at 4.0.  I don't know why the `ylim` does such a strange thing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the `boundaries` argument to `colorbar`:

```
plt.colorbar(sc, cax=cax1, boundaries=sc.get_array())
```

I don't know whether `sc.get_array()` is always the right choice here, but `get_array` is the ScalarMappable method that is supposed to get the data to be mapped onto colors, so it seems like a reasonable choice.  (For contour sets, `colorbar` automatically grabs the contour levels and uses them as the boundaries.)

Comment: Ooo!  That is good to know.  However .... maybe I do care about detail, I was thinking of keeping the smooth gradient.  This gives me nice clear "steps", but the real data I'm plotting is actually a bunch of very unevenly distributed floating point numbers.  Can boundaries take any arbitrary array?

Comment: Aha!  I just tried it with `boundaries=np.linspace(-4,1,101)`, and it looks lovely.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in a few different ways, however it sounds like what you're really wanting is a custom colormap created from a portion of another colormap:

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

# Let's create a new colormap from a region of another colormap.
cmap = plt.get_cmap('BrBG_r')
colors = cmap(np.linspace(0, 5 / 8.0, 20))
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my cmap', colors)

# And now let's plot some data...
x, y, z = np.random.random((3, 10))
z = 5 * z - 4

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scat = ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=200, cmap=cmap, vmin=-4, vmax=1)
cbar = fig.colorbar(scat)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you'd prefer a discrete colormap, you can do something similar to:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import from_levels_and_colors

# Let's create a new set of colors from a region of another colormap.
ncolors = 10
cmap = plt.get_cmap('BrBG_r')
colors = cmap(np.linspace(0, 5 / 8.0, ncolors - 1))

# We'll then create a new colormap from that set of colors and tie it
# to specific values
levels = np.linspace(-4, 1, ncolors)
cmap, norm = from_levels_and_colors(levels, colors)

x, y, z = np.random.random((3, 10))
z = 5 * z - 4

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scat = ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=200, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
cbar = fig.colorbar(scat)
cbar.set_ticks(range(-4, 2))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, also nice!  Actually, the 0 to 5/8 in your first example got me thinking about why the `ylim` worked so funny ... turns out that the cbar ylimits (despite the ticks) work from 0 to 1 just as the colorbar values do .... I tried `cb.ax.set_ylim(0, 5/8.)` and it also worked!